# Cannot use Go Commands of go libraries. [$GOBIN or $GOPATH problem, Windows]

Tags: go, gopath, fyne

When I get go libraries from github, I can use them in code. But I cannot use their commands. For example, after "go get annie", I try to use its command, e.g."annie bebe.be/be/bebe". But I get "*The term 'annie' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*"

Another example is Fyne. I've installed with "go get fyne.io/fyne". I can create an application with it. But I cannot use "fyne package" command.

Just reinstalled go 1.14. Windows 10. "$env:GOPATH" gives "*C:\Users\Bekassyl/golang*". "$env:GOBIN" gives "*C:\Users\Bekassyl\golang\bin*".

Please help.

---

You guys mean this, right?
[$GOBIN is in Path now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJdU2.jpg)

Still doesn't work

Comment: Update your `PATH` to include your `GOBIN` (not your `GOPATH` - that won't help!)

Comment: @Adrian My bad. GOBIN not GOPATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fyne binary is installed by running ‘go get fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne’ as is common with go libraries the root of the project is the API and the supporting applications are in the ‘cmd/‘ subpackage. See https://tour.fyne.io/introduction/packaging.html or https://fyne.io/develop/distribution .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the value of `$env:GOBIN` to your windows `PATH` environment variable.

You might also need to open a new `cmd` or `powershell` window for this to take effect.

Comment: "$env:GOBIN" gives "C:\Users\Bekassyl\golang\bin". So, I've added "C:\Users\Bekassyl\golang\bin" to Path env variable both for User Variables and System Variables. But still I cannot use "fyne install" or "fyne package".

Comment: Did you open a new terminal/shell or log out and back in to ensure the new variable was picked up?

Comment: Yeap, did both refreshenv and opened new powershell